# lapply function to look up neighbors in igraph (when not all nodes are found)

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to create a data set of network neighbors for a list of nodes. I though I could do this with an lapply function where I use the neighbors command. As an added complication, some of my lookup nodes aren't in the graph, but I can't get it to work regardless.

Here is an example:

```
edgelist <- read.table(text = "
A B
B C
C D
D E
C F
F G")  

testlist <- read.table(text = "
A
H
C
D
J")  

testlist2 <- read.table(text = "
A
C
B
D
E") 

library(igraph)
graph <- graph.data.frame(edgelist)
str(graph)

neighbors<- lapply(testlist2, function(p) {  #Each pledge_id
  temp=neighbors(graph,p)  #Find all the neighbors for that pledge 
  return(temp)
})

neighbors<- lapply(testlist, function(p) {  #Each pledge_id
  temp=neighbors(graph,p)  #Find all the neighbors for that pledge 
  return(temp)
})
```

Unfortunately, this returns hogwash in both cases. What am I missing?

My desired output would be something like this:

```
lookupnode neighbor
A    B
H    .
C    D
C    F
D    E
J    .
```

I know eventually I need to add a temp=data.table::rbindlist(temp) command in somewhere, but I don't think that is causing the hogwash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing is that you're creating a `data.frame` with the `read.table` functions and passing in that `data.frame` to `lapply` so it's iterating over the each vector, not the elements of the `V1` vector in the `data.frame`.

Second, that `V1` column is a factor (h/t to @Psidom for the factor hint).

Third, the `neighbors()` function is going to return graph vertices which (from my reckoning) need to be iterated over and have the `name` attribute returned.

Then, as you suggest, these need to be `rbind`ed into a `data.frame`:

```
get_neighbors <- function(graph, n) {

  do.call(rbind, lapply(n, function(x) {

    if (x %in% V(graph)$name) {

      nb <- neighbors(graph, x)

      if (length(nb) > 0) {
        data.frame(lookupnode=x,
                   neighbor=nb$name, # h/t @MrFlick for this shortcut
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      } else {
        data.frame(lookupnode=x, neighbor=NA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      }

    } else {  
      data.frame(lookupnode=x, neighbor=NA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    }

  }))

}

get_neighbors(graph, as.character(testlist$V1))
##   lookupnode neighbor
## 1          A        B
## 2          H     <NA>
## 3          C        D
## 4          C        F
## 5          D        E
## 6          J     <NA>

get_neighbors(graph, as.character(testlist2$V1))
##   lookupnode neighbor
## 1          A        B
## 2          C        D
## 3          C        F
## 4          B        C
## 5          D        E
## 6          E     <NA>
```

I wonder if Gabor can vectorize `neighbors()` on the C-side.

UPDATE:

The `ego` solution is only a tad different:

```
get_ego <- function(g, v, n=2) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(v, function(x) {
    if (x %in% V(g)$name) {
      data.frame(node=x,
                 ego_n=sapply(ego(g, n, x), function(y) { V(g)[y]$name }),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    } else {
      data.frame(node=x, ego_n=NA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    }
  }))
}
```

Comment: You can use `neighbor=nb$name` inside the data.frame rather than the `sapply`

Comment: This is great! Of course it is a dataframe. Whoops. Also  `x %in% V(graph)$name` is key and is going to be useful for me elsewhere in this project. Thanks!

Comment: This works really well with 1st degree neighbors (which is what I asked) but if I substitute in the `ego` function `ego(graph, 2, x)` it returns a list of 1 with class "igraph.vs". Length is 1, so it still triggers the first if statement, but the error "Error in data.frame(lookupnode = x, neighbor = nb$name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0 " implies to me that this can't be coerced into a data.frame. How would you modify in that case?