# Generate list of second-degree neighbors using lapply and igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I got some excellent advice here on how to lookup neighbors for a list of network nodes. See: [lapply function to look up neighbors in igraph (when not all nodes are found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645671/lapply-function-to-look-up-neighbors-in-igraph-when-not-all-nodes-are-found)

Now I need to do the same thing with second-degree neighbors. However, substituting either `ego` or `neighborhood` function into this loop produces an error.

```
edgelist <- read.table(text = "
A B
B C
C D
D E
C F
F G")  

testlist <- read.table(text = "
A
H
C
D
J")  

testlist2 <- read.table(text = "
A
C
B
D
E") 

library(igraph)
graph <- graph.data.frame(edgelist)
str(graph)

get_neighbors <- function(graph, n) {

  do.call(rbind, lapply(n, function(x) {

    if (x %in% V(graph)$name) {

      nb <- neighborhood(graph,2, x)  ##HERE##

      if (length(nb) > 0) {
        data.frame(lookupnode=x,
                   neighbor=nb$name, # h/t @MrFlick for this shortcut
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      } else {
        data.frame(lookupnode=x, neighbor=NA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      }

    } else {  
      data.frame(lookupnode=x, neighbor=NA, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    }

  }))

}

A=get_neighbors(graph, as.character(testlist$V1))
```

Error in data.frame(lookupnode = x, neighbor = nb$name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

I gather the issue is that ego and neighborhood can't be directly coerced into a data frame. I can use `unlist` and then put in a data frame, but the values I want end up as `row.names` not values that I can put into my output.

How can I create an output of second-degree neighbors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed

```
neighbor=nb$name, # h/t @MrFlick for this shortcut
```

to

```
neighbor=names(unlist(nb)), # h/t @MrFlick for this shortcut
```

and it is working for me now.

```
> A
   lookupnode neighbor
1           A        A
2           A        B
3           A        C
4           H     <NA>
5           C        C
6           C        B
7           C        D
8           C        F
9           C        A
10          C        E
11          C        G
12          D        D
13          D        C
14          D        E
15          D        B
16          D        F
17          J     <NA>
>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I needed to add `names` to pull the `row.names`.